# Wrong number of elements in structure

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

Given the following code

```
<cfset test = structNew()>
<cfset test[73] = "">
<cfset test["6r"] = "">
<cfdump var=#test#>
```

Can anyone explain why the structure only contains the the element **73** and not **6r**. Also a way to workaround this issue would be must appreciated? I am using coldfusion 9 on a windows 2008 SBS server.

---

Version 9.0.0.251028
Edition Enterprise

I also tested the code on version  9,0,1,274733 on a windows 7 machine, here the code runs fine.

---

[image: Screendump]

Comment: Is the integer 73 a requirement or could you write it as a string "73"?

Comment: Works for me and I'm on CF 9

Comment: Works as expected for me on CF 9.0.2.

Comment: Works for me on 9.0.1. Can you add a screenshot of your `<cfdump>` ?

Comment: Can you pls confirm that if you save that exact code (as per above; no more, no less), in a file, and browse to the file, you see only the `73` key? Because I'm now the fourth person to run that code on CF9 and it works as I'd expect (both keys are in the struct). You can demonstrate this to yourself by running it on cflive.net, which runs ColdFusion 9.0.2. I think there is something about your situation you're not telling us? Pls let is know what it is...

Comment: The code is precisely what i am running. I do not understand why nobody else sees this. CFlive runs the code correctly. But internally it does not.

Comment: Switch debugging on and verify no other CFML files are being called in which might interfere (Application.cf(c|m), or anything else). Can you also append `<cfdump var="#variables#"> to your code, and post the dump in your question.

Comment: Added a screendump. The code is executed in the root of our webfolder. No application.(cfm|cfc) is present here.

Comment: Longshot, but browser cache?  Output a UUID alongside each run of the code

Comment: Just a suggestion, try installing the various [CF 9 hotfixes](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/hot-fixes-coldfusion-9.html) and see if that fixes it

Comment: Also would using structInsert() work?  `structInsert(test, 73, ""); structInsert(test, "6r", "");`

Comment: @Gerry: Browser cache is not an issue here.

Comment: @duncan: StructInsert This will give the error:  Cannot insert item with key 6r.This key already exists. Will try the hotfixes.

Comment: @duncan: hotfix http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-9-struct-keys-cfswitch.html did the trick. Apparantly this was a known issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hotfix [cpsid_82547e](http://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/coldfusion-9-struct-keys-cfswitch.html) solves this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that I can't test in CF9.  I'm running CF10 and your example works fine there.  However this is probably worth a try:

```
<cfset test = structNew()>
<cfset test[73] = "">
<cfset key="6r">
<cfset test[key] = "">
<cfdump var="#test#">
```